# Prolog List, searching the language with more predecessors

Tags: list, prolog

I have a file 'linguagens.pl' where its code is like this:

```
linguagem('Flow-matic',1957).
linguagem('Fortran I',1957).
linguagem('Fortran II',1958).
linguagem('Algol 58',1958).
linguagem('Lisp',1959).

predecessora('COBOL','Flow-matic').
predecessora('Fortran II','Fortran I').
predecessora('Algol 58','Fortran I').
predecessora('Algol 60','Algol 58').
predecessora('Fortran IV','Fortran II').
```

but bigger.
linguagem(name, year) and predecessora (language L1, language L2 who precedes L1).

Now, I need to find the language L that has more predecessors.

```
?- lingcommaispre(L).
L = 'Swift'.
```

So far, I tried this:

```
n_predecessoras(L, List) :- setof(P, predecessora(L, P), List).

lingcommaispre_aux([], _, L, L).
lingcommaispre_aux([H|T], N1, L1, L) :- n_predecessoras(H, Lista2),
                                        length(Lista2, N2),
                                        N1 >= N2,
                                        lingcommaispre_aux(T, N1, L1, L).
lingcommaispre_aux([H|T], N1, _ , L) :- n_predecessoras(H, Lista2),
                                        length(Lista2, N2),
                                        N1 < N2, 
                                        lingcommaispre_aux(T, N2, H , L).

lingcommaispre(L) :- findall(L1, linguagem(L1, _), Lista),
                     lingcommaispre_aux(Lista, -1, _, L).
```

But it does not work. What I'm trying to do is: to find all the predecessor of a language L and put it in a List, so I get the length of the this list and compare it with the length of the previous language list.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `?- trace.` the execution, to locate where it fails.

But - for any language - there is a lot to gain investing time to learn about the ready to use tools.

Indeed, SWI-Prolog library(aggregate) is a big helper here: first I defined

```
n_predecessoras(L,N) :- aggregate(count, P^predecessora(P,L), N).
```

and then

```
?- aggregate(max(N,L), n_predecessoras(L,N), Max).
Max = max(2, 'Fortran I').
```

No more need to write a program...